# Guardar valores de VB6 en SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, combobox, vb6

Tengo esta interfaz:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando se presiona el botón añadir se agrega un UserControl con los mismos campos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces, la pregunta es: ¿Cómo hago para guardar los valores principales y los que se hayan añadido? Es decir, si el usuario presionó el botón añadir, ¿Cómo hago para guardar también esos valores?

Actualmente, este es todo el código de la interfaz:

```
Option Explicit
Private oldPos As Integer

Dim indice As Integer
Dim indicee As Integer

Dim cnn As Connection
Dim rs As Recordset
Dim sCon As String
Dim sql As Command

Private Sub btnAñadir_Click()
   indice = indice + 1
   indicee = indicee + 0

   Picture1.Visible = True

   Load uc1(indice)
   Set uc1(indice).Container = Picture1 
   uc1(indice).Visible = True
   uc1(indice).Top = IIf(indice = 1, 0, uc1(indice - 1).Top + uc1(indice - 1).Height + 20)


   Set lblTipo(indice).Container = uc1(indice)
   lblTipo(indice).Visible = True
   lblTipo(indice).Top = lblTipo(indice - 1).Top

   Load cmbAddTipo(indice)
   Set cmbAddTipo(indice).Container = uc1(indice)
   cmbAddTipo(indice).Visible = True
   cmbAddTipo(indice).Top = cmbAddTipo(indice - 1).Top
   CargarTablaEnCombo "SELECT [tipo] FROM dbo.[tipo_Numero]", Me.cmbAddTipo(indice), "tipo"


   Load lblAddPrefijo(indice)
   Set lblAddPrefijo(indice).Container = uc1(indice)
   lblAddPrefijo(indice).Visible = True
   lblAddPrefijo(indice).Top = lblAddPrefijo(indice - 1).Top

   Load txtAddPrefijo(indice)
   Set txtAddPrefijo(indice).Container = uc1(indice)
   txtAddPrefijo(indice).Visible = True
   txtAddPrefijo(indice).Top = txtAddPrefijo(indice - 1).Top


   Load lblAddNum(indice)
   Set lblAddNum(indice).Container = uc1(indice)
   lblAddNum(indice).Visible = True
   lblAddNum(indice).Top = lblAddNum(indice - 1).Top

   Load txtAddNumero(indice)
   Set txtAddNumero(indice).Container = uc1(indice)
   txtAddNumero(indice).Visible = True
   txtAddNumero(indice).Top = txtAddNumero(indice - 1).Top


   Load chkAddPrincipal(indice)
   Set chkAddPrincipal(indice).Container = uc1(indice)
   chkAddPrincipal(indice).Visible = True
   chkAddPrincipal(indice).Top = chkAddPrincipal(indice - 1).Top


   Load chkAddActual(indice)
   Set chkAddActual(indice).Container = uc1(indice)
   chkAddActual(indice).Visible = True
   chkAddActual(indice).Top = chkAddActual(indice - 1).Top


   Load lblAddVin(indice)
   Set lblAddVin(indice).Container = uc1(indice)
   lblAddVin(indice).Visible = True
   lblAddVin(indice).Top = lblAddVin(indice - 1).Top

   Load cmbAddVinculo(indice)
   Set cmbAddVinculo(indice).Container = uc1(indice)
   cmbAddVinculo(indice).Visible = True
   cmbAddVinculo(indice).Top = cmbAddVinculo(indice - 1).Top
   CargarTablaEnCombo "SELECT [tipoVinculo] FROM dbo.[tipo_Vinculo]", Me.cmbAddVinculo(1), "tipoVinculo"

   If indice = 3 Then
   indice = 0
   Me.btnAñadir.Enabled = False
   End If

End Sub

Private Sub btnGuardar_Click()
    Dim sql As String
    sql = "INSERT INTO ejemplo(nombre) VALUES("
    sql = sql & "'" & cmbAddTipo.Count & "',"
    sql = sql & "'" & txtAddPrefijo.Text & "',"
    sql = sql & "'" & txtAddNumero.Text & "',"
    sql = sql & "'" & chkAddPrincipal.Value & "',"
    sql = sql & "'" & chkAddActual.Value & "',"
    sql = sql & "'" & cmbAddVinculo.Count & "',"
    sql = sql & "'" & txtTimer.Text & "')"
    cnn.Execute sql
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()

   Dim theDate As Date
   theDate = Format(Now(), "short date")
   TextBox1.Text = theDate

   scrollAdd.Min = 0
   scrollAdd.Max = 3000
   scrollAdd.SmallChange = Screen.TwipsPerPixelX * 10
   scrollAdd.LargeChange = scrollAdd.SmallChange

   Call IniciarConexion
   CargarTablaEnCombo "SELECT [tipo] FROM dbo.[tipo_Numero]", Me.cmbAddTipo(0), "tipo"
   CargarTablaEnCombo "SELECT [tipoVinculo] FROM dbo.[tipo_Vinculo]", Me.cmbAddVinculo(0), "tipoVinculo"

End Sub

Sub CargarTablaEnCombo(ByVal sql As String, comboBox As Object, ByVal Campo As String)
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    rs.Open sql, cnn, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic
    While Not rs.EOF
        If Not IsNull(rs.Fields(Campo)) Then
            comboBox.AddItem rs.Fields(Campo)
        End If
    rs.MoveNext
    Wend
End Sub

Function cerrarRecordset(R As Recordset)
    On Error Resume Next
    If Not R Is Nothing Then
        If R.State = adStateOpen Then
            R.Close
            Set R = Nothing
        Else
            Set R = Nothing
        End If
    End If
    Err.Clear
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function

Private Sub IniciarConexion()
    Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection
    With cnn
        .CursorLocation = adUseClient
        .Open "PROVIDER=MSDASQL;driver={SQL Server};server=server;uid=uid;pwd=password;database=database;"
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Unload(Cancel As Integer)
On Local Error Resume Next
cnn.Close
Set cnn = Nothing
End Sub

Private Sub scrollAdd_Change()
   ScrollControls
End Sub

Private Sub scrollAdd_Scroll()
   ScrollControls
End Sub

Private Sub ScrollControls()
   Dim c As Control

   For Each c In Me.Controls
      If c.Container.Name = "Picture1" And Not TypeOf c Is VScrollBar Then
         c.Top = c.Top + (oldPos - scrollAdd.Value)
      End If
   Next

   oldPos = scrollAdd.Value
End Sub

Private Sub txtAddNumero_KeyPress(Index As Integer, KeyAscii As Integer)
If (KeyAscii >= 97) And (KeyAscii < 122) Or (KeyAscii >= 65) And (KeyAscii < 90) Then
  MsgBox "No se permiten letras."
  KeyAscii = 8
End If

End Sub

Private Sub txtAddPrefijo_KeyPress(Index As Integer, KeyAscii As Integer)
If (KeyAscii >= 97) And (KeyAscii < 122) Or (KeyAscii >= 65) And (KeyAscii < 90) Then
  MsgBox "No se permiten letras."
  KeyAscii = 8
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola Franqo Balsamo: VB6 me queda un poco muy lejos, pero lo que tienes que hacer es en la sentencia de guardado, recuperar el valor de todos los controles (tienes un indice por lo que he visto para saber la cantidad), formando un bucle.
Las sentencias de insercción en sql para 1 o varias filas son

```
 Dim sql As String
sql = "INSERT INTO ejemplo(nombre) VALUES("
// aquí el inicio del bucle. Y extraes todos los valores
sql = sql & "'" & cmbAddTipo.Count & "',"
sql = sql & "'" & txtAddPrefijo.Text & "',"
sql = sql & "'" & txtAddNumero.Text & "',"
sql = sql & "'" & chkAddPrincipal.Value & "',"
sql = sql & "'" & chkAddActual.Value & "',"
sql = sql & "'" & cmbAddVinculo.Count & "',"
sql = sql & "'" & txtTimer.Text & "')"
// aquí el final del bucle.
// Si el bucle solo tiene una fila terminas con punto y coma, sino terminas la fila     con una coma.
cnn.Execute sql
```

End Sub

Al final tu sentencia tiene que quedar como. Insert into ejemplo (col1, col2, col3....) values (row1val1, row1val2, row1fal3...),(row2val1, row2val2, row3val3...),(....);
Y esta es la query que envias al Motor. 1 Sola query para todas las inserciones.